# MEF in MVC 5 with WebAPI2 - best practices

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, mef

I'm building a simple website and I would like to be able to easily plug in modules such as News and Events into it so I can reuse those in the future. After a bit of digging around I found that the best way to do this is MEF. Using [Kenny Tordeur's walkthrough](http://kennytordeur.blogspot.in/2012/08/mef-in-aspnet-mvc-4-and-webapi.html) I got the site in a semi-working state.
I then made a few changes and extensions based on [Long Le's Blog](http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/28/ioc-dependency-injection-manage-extensiblity-framework-mef-servicelocator-in-net-4-mvc-4-webapi-idependencyresolver-with-closed-classes-e-g-twilio-apis/). Still no joy. my current problem is that my MefDependencyResolver is supposed to provide an instance of System.Web.Http.Hosting.IHostBufferPolicySelector but as the only thing it's trying to do is GetExports() on the CompositionContainer, and an implementation of this interface hasn't been exported, this is not really working at all.

I now have the feeling that I got the wrong idea entirely.

My website is built using ASP.Net MVC 5 and it's reasonably simple at this point. My NewsModule, that I'm trying to "plug in" using MEF is also in MVC 5 and it's using WebAPI 2 for a set of AngularJS requests (e.g. getting the news).

To make things worse, the module's architecture is based on [this blog](http://chsakell.com/2015/02/15/asp-net-mvc-solution-architecture-best-practices/) - which I found very useful but it now means that the API controllers in the module have dependencies that need to be injected somehow.

So, a bit of code:
My **Global.asax** looks like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        MefConfig.RegisterMef(null);
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MefViewEngine(MefConfig.GetPlugins()));
    }
```

The **MefConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterMef(TypeCatalog typeCatalog)
    {
        var compositionContainer = ConfigureContainer(typeCatalog);
        ServiceLocator
            .SetLocatorProvider(() => new MefServiceLocator(compositionContainer));

        ControllerBuilder
            .Current.SetControllerFactory(
            new MefControllerFactory(compositionContainer));

        GlobalConfiguration
            .Configuration
            .DependencyResolver =
            new MefDependencyResolver(compositionContainer);

        //compositionContainer.ComposeParts(); IS this not needed??
    }

    private static CompositionContainer ConfigureContainer(ComposablePartCatalog composablePartCatalog)
    {

        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));

        foreach (var plugin in GetPlugins())
        {
            var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Modules", plugin));
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(directoryCatalog);

        }

        if (composablePartCatalog != null)
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(composablePartCatalog);

        return new CompositionContainer(
            catalog,
            new MefNameValueCollectionExportProvider(
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings));
    }

    public static List<string> GetPlugins()
    {
        var pluginFolders = new List<string>();
        var plugins = Directory.GetDirectories(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Modules")).ToList();
        plugins.ForEach(s =>
        {
            var di = new DirectoryInfo(s);
            pluginFolders.Add(di.Name);
        });
        return pluginFolders;
    }
```

The **MefControllerFactory.cs**

```
public class MefControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly CompositionContainer m_CompositionContainer;
    public MefControllerFactory(CompositionContainer container)
    {
        m_CompositionContainer = container;
    }

    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        var controller = GetInstance<IController>(controllerName) ??
                         GetControllerInstance(requestContext, typeof(Controller));

        return controller;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(
    RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        var name = AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(controllerType);
        var export = m_CompositionContainer
            .GetExports(controllerType, null, name).SingleOrDefault();

        IController result;

        if (null != export)
            result = export.Value as IController;
        else
        {
            result = base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
            m_CompositionContainer.ComposeParts(result);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public SessionStateBehavior GetControllerSessionBehavior(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        return SessionStateBehavior.Default;
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        var disposableController = controller as IDisposable;

        disposableController?.Dispose();
    }

    private T GetInstance<T>(string contractName = null)
    {
        var type = default(T);
        if (m_CompositionContainer == null) return type;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contractName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contractName))
        {
            return m_CompositionContainer.GetExportedValue<T>();
        }

        var export = m_CompositionContainer.GetExports(typeof(T), null, contractName).SingleOrDefault();
        if (export != null)
        {
            return (T)export.Value;
        }
        return type;
    }
}
```

and the **MefDependencyResolver.cs**

```
public class MefDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly CompositionContainer m_Container;

    public MefDependencyResolver(CompositionContainer container)
    {
        m_Container = container;
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {

        var name = AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType);
        var export = m_Container.GetExports(serviceType, null, name).SingleOrDefault();

        return export?.Value;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        var name = AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType);
        var exports = m_Container.GetExports(serviceType, null, name);
        var createdObjects = new List<object>();

        var enumerable = exports as Lazy<object, object>[] ?? exports.ToArray();
        if (enumerable.Any()) createdObjects.AddRange(enumerable.Select(export => export.Value));
        return createdObjects;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

Part of the **ArticleController** in the News module:

```
[Export(typeof(IController))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
[System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix("api/article")]
public class ArticleController : ApiController
{
    private IArticleService ArticleService { get; }
    private IAttachmentService AttachmentService { get; }

    public ArticleController(IArticleService articleService, IAttachmentService attachmentService)
    {
        ArticleService = articleService;
        AttachmentService = attachmentService;
    }


    [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<ArticleListView>))]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var articles = ArticleService.GetArticles();

        if (articles == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(articles.OrderByDescending(a => a.Created).Select(a => new ArticleListView(a)));
    }
```

Still in the News module, i have this resource for the articles:

```
var ArticleService = function ($resource) {
return $resource('/api/article/:id',{id:'@id'}, {
    update:{method:'PUT'}
});
```

Which then gets queried from the Controller Article.query($scope.articles, function (resp){...}

My questions would be?

1. Is this the correct way to use MEF?
2. Is it possible to use MEF when my module's controllers have DI?
3. If the above to answers are both "Yes" then what am I doing wrong in the MefDependencyResolver that ends up in an exception?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: wondering if how did u finally solve this issue?